# Issue Running Python Script using os.listdir()

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I am using os.listdir() to list contents of a directory and print those contents:

```
import os

def scanfiles(path):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
    print(item)

path = str(os.path.normpath(input("Please enter a path: \n")))
scanfiles(path)
```

This program will work if, at the prompt, I enter something like: '/foo/bar' 
(with quotes).

However, if I do not enter quotes, such as:
/foo/bar
the program gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanfiles.py", line 7, in <module>
  path = str(os.path.normpath(input("Please enter a path: \n")))
  File "<string>", line 1
    /foo/bar
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I need a way to make this run without entering quotes before and after the path.

I don't want to make a new string my concatenating quotes on each end because that doesn't seem very elegant to me.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap `os.path.normpath` in `str()`? I don't understand what you mean about concatenating quotes?

Comment: i added str() because I thought it would solve this issue.  My concatenating quotes I mean doing something along the lines of path = str("'" + /foo/bar + "'")

Comment: Are you saying when you print it out, you want it to print `"/foo/bar"` instead of `/foo/bar`? In that case you could do `print(f'"{item}"')`. Currently it doesn't add any quotes.

Comment: When you run the program there is a prompt that says "Please enter a path:".  I want to be able to enter /foo/bar, not '/foo/bar'.  The function that prints appears to work fine provided I have entered my path with quotes

Comment: It works fine for me without adding quotes.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry the issue was that I was running with python and not python3.  I had previously set python as an alias to python3 but it didnt stick.  WHen I ran with python3 it worked my bad.